# Lengths must match to compare Error When trying to create subplots with different Number of values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis, valueerror

I tried to create 10 subplots and the columns I'm using for these subplots are different. Therefore, it raises the error in the title. Is there a way to prevent that?

Here is the code I've tried and the full error code.
PS: newvac and news are the column names I'm trying to plot; I'm trying to plot these two columns for country variables and countriess variable has 5 country names. And each country has a different number of values for these columns.
Error code:"ValueError: Lengths must match to compare"

```
figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=2,figsize=(20,16))
for i in range(5):
    country = [i for i in countriess]
    for j in range(2):
        axes[i,1].plot(countriesss[countriesss['location'] == country]['date'],countriesss[countriesss['location'] == country]['newvac'])
        axes[i,2].plot(countriesss[countriesss['location'] == country]['date'],countriesss[countriesss['location'] == country]['news'])
figure.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you put the full error as text in your question?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I have.